# How do I completely disable bell in screen (both visual and audio)

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen, tty

In screen, is there a way to completely disable bell ?

I know you can switch to audio bell instead of the visual one and have already done that and have also specified no bell in putty so I don't hear anything but whenever there is a bell in one window, I see an annoying popup on the other windows say "bell in window 1" and so on.

Any idea on how to get rid of it ?

Comment: I really hate bell !!! Why do they even have them ? Makes no sense to me. (Well I know there use but they really annoy you, don't they ? :) )

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To permanently disable the visual bell, you need to add the following command to your **.screenrc** file:

```
  vbell off
```

I haven't tested it, but adding the additional line to your **.screenrc** file should disable the message bell:

```
  bell_msg ""
```

To disable it in a session (temporarily, not permanently), issue the following command from the session:

```
  CTRL+A, CTRL+G
```

See the man page for screen (section 'CUSTOMIZATION') for more information.

Comment: Thanks man bell_msg "" did the trick. I already have vbell off.

Comment: bell_msg "" doesn't "disable" the bell but it does disable the popup (you will still hear/see it in the active window).  vbell off and CTRL+A,CTRL+G do the same thing and change between audio and visual bell (so they have no affect on this problem).

Comment: @whitey04 read the question and answer more carefully.  You comments are either wrong or haven't addressing the issues in the question and answer.